# entering data in Numbers

Tags: macos, numbers

When I hit Return after entering a number in a cell, the cursor automatically drops down to the next row under the cell.  How can I disable that, so it stays on the cell I entered and I can move on my own to wherever I want to make my next entry?
I use the num pad when entering into a spreadsheet and it is habitual to hit "enter" after inputting numbers into a cell, then arrowing to wherever I need to go next (often to the next column rather than the next row.) There was a way to disable the automatic movement in Excel, but I've not been able to find a way to disable in Numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly what you've asked for, but try pressing <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd> while the cell is still in edit mode, instead of just <kbd>Return</kbd>. This should keep the same cell selected.

**Edit after OP clarification:**

There is no option to disable cursor movement on Enter in the latest version of Numbers. It used to be there in earlier versions (pre 3.0, I believe).

Comment: That adds another line in the cell (a carriage return) nice tip, though.

Comment: @bjbk are you sure? I've just opened Numbers to double-check, and carriage return in cell is done by Alt+Return or Ctrl+Return.

Comment: Sorry, right. But command return goes to the parent. (Selects the table)

Comment: I believe, a table is selected, if you were not editing a cell, but just had it selected (no cursor blinking inside a cell). However, in a cell edit mode, Cmd+Return ends editing and keeps that cell selected, as I said before. At least that's what my version of Numbers does, and what [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH23737?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US) says :) (Stop editing the cell and select the cell: Command-Return; 
Stop editing the cell and select the table: Command-Return twice; )

Comment: Excellent. Mine was selecting the table. I must not have been in edit mode. Good one!